# How can I access individual values in a gsp file that are generated in a <g:each> tag?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following code in a gsp file, used for editing individual values of an existing list (patientPts)

```
<g:each var="points" in="${patientPts}">
            <b>Term: ${points.term} - <g:if test="${points.type.equals('C')}">Calculus<br>
                </g:if> <g:else>Perio<br>
                </g:else></b>
            <label for="${points.id}01">Class 0/1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="class_01" value="${points.class_01}"
                id="${points.id}01">
            <br>
            <label for="${points.id}2">Class 2:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="number" name="class_2" value="${points.class_2}"
                id="${points.id}2">
            <br>
            <label for="${points.id}3">Class 3:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="number" name="class_3" value="${points.class_3}"
                id="${points.id}3">
            <br>
            <label for="${points.id}4">Class 4:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="number" name="class_4" value="${points.class_4}"
                id="${points.id}4">
            <br>
        </g:each>
        <br>
        <div class="buttons">
            <g:link value="Save" action="save"
                params="${[patientPts: patientPts]}">Save</g:link>
            <g:actionSubmit value="Cancel" action="index" />
        </div>
```

patientPts is a list of PatientPoints objects with the following attributes

```
String courseKey; //Stores the course key of the course for the patient points object
String term; // Stores the term of the patient points object
String type; // Stores the type of the patient points object
Double class_01; //Stores the points for the class 0 and class 1
Double class_2;  //Stores the points for the class 2
Double class_3; //Stores the points for the class 3
Double class_4; //Stores the points for the class 4
```

Which displays this
[image: Grade Adjustments edit]

I have a save action in my controller in which I need to be able to get at all of these objects and save the changes that are made to them, if any. I am having trouble doing this because I cant figure out how to refer to each text field separately, when they are all generated by the  tag. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the array or list binding syntax in your GSP. You could put the PatientPts objects in a Set inside of a command object such as:

```
class PatientCommand {
    Set<PatientPts> patientPts
}
```

In your GSP, you want to bind using the index notation:

```
<g:each var="points" in="${commandInstance.patientPts}" status="i">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="patientPts[${i}]class_01" value="${points.class_01}" 
           id="${points.id}01">
```

When the form is submitted and bound to the PatientCommand, the data binder will create indidual PatientPts objects and bind them into the Set (creating and growing it automatically).

Comment: I appreciate this answer but I simply dont understand what it is you're really saying. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The `name` on the `input` is the most important ingredient for data binding. Essentially, that will make its way into the `params` in a form determined by the format. Using the `[]` syntax tells Grails that we are working with a list of things. If you debug and break in your controller, take a look at `params` and you'll start to understand how it works. Basically, the data binder will see `patientPts[0].class_01 = 'foo'` and understand that it needs to create a new `PatientPts` object and then bind `class_01` into the first `[0]` element in the set.

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on this all day and it has been driving me crazy. I'll keep you posted on my progress.

Comment: Where do I make this PatientCommand class? How is the gsp file referencing it in the each tag?

Comment: Typically you put the command class at the bottom of the Controller. The GSP doesn't really need to _know_ about the command class (remember, whats important is the `name` and how that maps to the fields in the command class). So, if you make your controller method, say `def update(PatientCommand patient)`, Grails will do all the work and you'll have a `patient` object with a Set of PatientPts in it.

Comment: So then when does a PatientPoints object get passed into the update method, and how? Also, im confused about this line
name="patientPts[${i}]class_01"
Why and how is it referencing variable 'i' from the controller inside the dollar sign brackets? Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I guess `PatientPoints` is a domain class. You may use a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) wrapping a collection of `PatientPoints`:

```
class PatientPointsUpdate {
    List<PatientPoints> patientPoints
}
```

You will have to modify the view accordingly (adding a missing input for the `id` and update the name of existing ones):

```
<g:each var="points" in="${patientPts}" status="i">
    <g:hiddenField name="patientPointsUpdate[i].id" value="points.id" />
    <b>Term: ${points.term} - <g:if test="${points.type.equals('C')}">Calculus<br>
    </g:if> <g:else>Perio<br>
    </g:else></b>
    <label for="${points.id}01">Class 0/1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="patientPointsUpdate[i].class_01" value="${points.class_01}"
           id="${points.id}01">
    <br>
    <label for="${points.id}2">Class 2:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="number" name="patientPointsUpdate[i].class_2" value="${points.class_2}"
           id="${points.id}2">
    <br>
    <label for="${points.id}3">Class 3:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="number" name="patientPointsUpdate[i].class_3" value="${points.class_3}"
           id="${points.id}3">
    <br>
    <label for="${points.id}4">Class 4:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="number" name="patientPointsUpdate[i].class_4" value="${points.class_4}"
           id="${points.id}4">
    <br>
</g:each>
```

If everything goes fine in your `save` action will be able to retrieve and update `PatientPoints` instances in database from the data contained in the command object:

```
def save(PatientPointsUpdate patientPointsUpdate) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer but I simply dont understand what it is you're really saying. Can you elaborate more?